# Can't get Perl Chart (gnuplot) to label all tics on axis

Tags: perl, gnuplot

Using `Chart::Gnuplot` in perl.

The x axis is to be for date/time.

I'm specifying

```
timeaxis => "x"   (seems to work)
```

I'm using

```
timefmt => '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'
```

to read the elements in the array ref passed to xdata in the `Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new`.  (that seems to work too)

Using

```
xtics => {labelfmt => "%m-%d %H", rotate => -90}
```

to display the labels the way I want them.  (that all seems to work too)

And indeed, everything looks good except for the fact that it's only labeling a handful of tics on the x (date/time) axis.  I want to label them all (or every other one, or have some control over this)

I found lots of examples of how to do this for numbers (note dates) using... start, incr, end, etc... .  And I tried lots of experiments to get this to work.  But I think I've exhausted all that I can find on this googling around and I'm still stuck :-(

And so, if there is any advise on how to get this to label all the tics with the date/time, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you look through all the examples regarding ticks at https://metacpan.org/release/Chart-Gnuplot?

Comment: Doing that in gnuplot itself is a bit tricky, you must use `xticklabel` and manually format the time for the tics: `plot 'file.dat' u 1:0::xticlabel(strftime("%d.%m.%Y", timecolumn(1)))`. But I have no idea how that would be done via Chart::Gnuplot. Judging from search.cpan.org/dist/Chart-Gnuplot/lib/Chart/Gnuplot.pm I would say, that it's not possible.

Comment: Maybe you can use `xtics => labels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xtics => { labels=>[...] }` but you need to respect that

> In case of timeseries data, position values must be given as quoted dates or times according to the format **timefmt**.

from [gnuplot documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html).

Assuming the array `@x` contains the data set's time values in **timefmt**, x-tick labels can be forced at each of those times like this.

```
xtics => {
    labels=>[map { q(').$_.q(') } @x]
}
```

There are plenty of ways to add single quotes around each time, but I think the `map` above is cleanest.

You can of course provide your own labels, just make sure they are quoted properly and the same as **timefmt**. I think Perl's `q()` quoting operator is the way to go.

```
labels=>[ q('2005-6-7_07:04:53') , q('2005-6-7_07:05:10') ]
```

#### Full working example

Here is a full working example, modified from the gnuplot tick examples.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use Chart::Gnuplot;

    # Change the date time format of the tic labels
    # - the solution is the same as change the number format

    # Date array
    my @x = qw(
    2005-6-7_07:00:00
    2005-6-7_07:05:00
    2005-6-7_07:10:00
    2005-6-7_07:15:00
    );

    my @y = qw(
    3562279127
    3710215571
    3877469703
    3876354871
    );

    # Create the chart object
    my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
        output   => 'test.png',
        xtics    => {
            rotate => -90,
            labelfmt => "%m-%d %H",
            labels=>[map { q(').$_.q(') } @x]
        },
        timeaxis => "x", # declare that x-axis uses time format
    );

    # Data set object
    my $data = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
        xdata   => \@x,
        ydata   => \@y,
        style   => 'linespoints',
        timefmt => '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S',
    );

    # Plot the graph
    $chart->plot2d($data);
```

Without the `labels`, you'll get something like this.

[image: Without specifying labels you get automatic ones]

With the `labels`, you'll get something like this.

[image: Fixing label locations to provided values]